# In an abelian category, an object $G$ is a generator iff for any nonzero object $X$, $\operatorname{Hom}(G, X) \neq 0$

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

In an abelian category, an object $G$ is a generator iff for any nonzero object $X$, $\operatorname{Hom}(G, X) \neq 0$

Would you give me a proof or some references?

I could show the “only if” part.

I don’t know that at which I use the abelian-ness of the category.
In the proof of “only if” part, I didn’t use it.

Comment: I know that as the definition, so could you please tell me your definition of a generator? that might help considerably

Comment: @Enkidu: an object $G$ of a category is a generator if $\text{Hom}(G, -)$ is faithful. The definition zom gives I have seen called "weak generator" (at least I call it that).

Comment: @zom: I only know how to prove this if $G$ is projective. Where did you see it stated that it was true in general?

Comment: @Enkidu Sorry, i didn’t know other definition. My definition is the same to the Qiaochu Yuan ‘s definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proof under the additional hypothesis that $G$ is projective; I don't know either a proof or a counterexample without this assumption. (**Edit:** In the comments Jeremy Rickard gives the example of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in the category of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$-modules).

Let $G$ be a *weak generator*, meaning that if $\text{Hom}(G, X) = 0$ then $X = 0$ (so $\text{Hom}(G, -)$ reflects zero objects), which is also projective. We want to show that $G$ is a generator, meaning that $\text{Hom}(G, -)$ is faithful, or equivalently that if $f : X \to Y$ is a morphism such that $\text{Hom}(G, f) = 0$ then $f = 0$ (so $\text{Hom}(G, -)$ reflects zero morphisms).

We have that $f = 0$ iff $\text{im}(f) = 0$. Since $G$ is projective, $\text{Hom}(G, -)$ is exact, so preserves kernels and cokernels, and hence preserves images. . This means that if $f : X \to Y$ is a morphism, then

$$\text{Hom}(G, \text{im}(f)) \cong \text{im}(\text{Hom}(G, f)).$$

So we have equivalences

$$\text{Hom}(G, f) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \text{im}(\text{Hom}(G, f)) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \text{Hom}(G, \text{im}(f)) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \text{im}(f) = 0 \Leftrightarrow f = 0$$

which is the desired result.

Without the hypothesis that $G$ is projective you get only that $\text{Hom}(G, -)$ preserves kernels and so reflects monomorphisms (using $\text{ker}(f)$ instead of $\text{im}(f)$ above).

Comment: For a counterexample without “projective”: in the category of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$-modules, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a weak generator, but not a generator.

Comment: @Jeremy: oh, very nice, thank you! This answers a question I couldn’t resolve when I wrote a blog post on generators.

Comment: Thank you so much!